# Trying to populate drop down or select menu

Tags: php

I am trying to populate two dropdown menus with items in a lookup table. So far I have this:

```
<label for="search_for_<?php echo $field['name']; ?>"><?php echo $field['label']; ?></label>
<select name="search" class="select">
<option value="<?php echo $field['name']; ?>"><?php echo $field['label']; ?></option>
</select>
```

which gives me the drop down menus but only populates them with the names of the columns and not the data in the rows.

Searched high and low for this but most suggestions remove even the 'header' and leave the drop downs blank.

Comment: uhhh? where is the code?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Sorry I am a total noob when it comes to this....

Comment: I can send the complete file I am working with and a link to the site if you like

Comment: we are seriously lacking some code here: 1) where is the data coming from? your sql would also be nice. 2) this template you posted is rather incomplete or completely bonkers. I will leave a partial answer so that you may have pointers. If you leave me some more clues (I mean `code`) then maybe qe can give you a full answer^^